# Flask redirect is not working properly after registration

Tags: python, flask

My registration code looks like this

```
@app.route('/register/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    # Output message if something goes wrong...
    msg = ''
    # Check if "username", "password" and "email" POST requests exist (user submitted form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form and 'email' in request.form:
        # Create variables for easy access
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        email = request.form['email']
        plan = request.form['plan']
        # Check if account exists using MySQL
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s AND email = %s', (username,email,))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        # If account exists show error and validation checks
        if account:
            msg = 'Conta já existe!'
        elif not re.match(r'[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+', email):
            msg = 'E-mail inválido!'
        elif not re.match(r'[A-Za-z0-9]+', username):
            msg = 'Usuário deve conter apenas letras e números!'
        elif not username or not password or not email:
            msg = 'Por favor, preencha os campos!'
        else:
            # Token for recovery of password
            token = secrets.token_hex(16)
            salt = bcrypt.gensalt()
            hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), salt)
            # Account doesnt exists and the form data is valid, now insert new account into accounts table
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO accounts VALUES (NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', (username, salt, hashed, email,token,))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            # render_template('payment.html', username=username, plan=plan)
            msg = f'Olá,{username}! Você se registrou. Faça agora o pagamento.'
            redirect(url_for('payment',username=username,plan=plan))
    # Show registration form with message (if any)
    return render_template('register.html', msg=msg)
```

It happens, that after a successful registration the code does not redirect to this part of the code:

```
@app.route('/payment/<username>/<plan>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def payment(username,plan):
    amount = 0
    if plan == 'basic':
        amount = 10
    elif plan == 'intermediate':
        amount = 50
    elif plan == 'advanced':
        amount = 250
    pix = charge_ammount(username,amount)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        check_if_is_paid()
    return render_template('payment.html',username=username,plan = plan,
                            msg = 'Aponte a câmera e faça o pix, depois clique em pagar',
                            pix = pix)
```

Simply nothing happens, what could it be since other redirects are working fine?

Comment: `return redirect(...)`

Comment: @arthur have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You missed return keyword

```
return redirect(url_for('payment',username=username,plan=plan))
```